# "Error Creating Window Handle" in my .NET console application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, scheduled-tasks

We have a VB.NET Console Application used to do some data synchronization tasks between 2 servers. The application is running every 10 minutes, without any problem, launched by Windows Task Scheduler.

Now we changed the server where the application is running, and we started to get these errors on the new server:

"Error Creating Window Handle".

And the curious thing is that we get the errors every 3 HOURS!
I mean, the application is running every 10 minutes, but we only get the errors in the next runs: 00:00 - 03:00 - 06:00 - 09:00 - 12:00 - 15:00 - 18:00 - 21:00

What can be the reason of this? The application is doing the same steps on each run... What could I do to catch the problem on these runs?

Comment: Not a lot of detail to go on, however the most likly cause is a Memory or Handle leak which can occur if you are not correclty disposing of objects. Does you app have any UI, Message Dialgos etc? Have you tried added an unhandled exception handler to capture the exact location of the error in your code?

Comment: @apc - All the steps are in a a Try-Catch block, that is the reason because I receive an email with the error message. Because the error is catched and then sent by e-mail to me. That is what I have in the Cacth code. I will add the Stack Trace to try to find out the exact line/lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

After see the Stack Trace I could realize that the problem was always related to the class System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, which is used to convert RTF text to Plain text.

What I did to solve the problem was to create the object in a USING statement.
By this way you ensure the object is disposed out of the using block, probably this was the cause of the errors... Since I did the change yesterday I didn't receive the error again.

```
Using rtb As New System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()
    rtb.Rtf = strText
    strText = rtb.Text
End Using
```